# TinyMCE upload file JSON error because of htaccess rewriterule

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, tinymce

I'm having trouble with the TinyMCE upload file option (using JSON) in combination with a `.htaccess` `RewriteRule`. I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (1:43)
```

I'm using this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+) page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

BUT...... I found that it works if I try to use the function on:

```
example.com/page.php?id=1
```

It doesn't work if the url is like this:

```
example.com/page/1
```

What could I be doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: An obvious difference between those two URLs is the path depth. If you are using relative client-side URLs then you will have problems. (Although I have no idea how this would relate to the JSON error - it seems unrelated.) You could (temporarily) try changing your URL structure to `/page-1` and `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to `^page-(\d+)$` - to rule this out.

Comment: @MrWhite “Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0” is typical for when the response was an HTML document - in this case probably the 404 error document, most likely due to the fact that, as you said, some relative path resolves to a different absolute URL now.

Comment: @MrWhite It works by changing the URL structure to /page-1 and the RewriteRule to ^page-(\d+)$. So that means it indeed has to do with the path. Will look into it further, as I prefer to keep the URL like page/1 for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: I got it to work with the help of you guys! Thank you so much. So the problem was indeed the relative path structure. To upload a file, a .php file was called:

`images_upload_url : upload.php`

AND

`xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);`

I changed this to the absolute path of this file and now it works! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Nicholas That's great, glad you got it working! You should submit that as an "answer" (and later accept it) - helps other readers and removes the question from the unanswered question queue. Thanks, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was as a result of using *relative* URLs in client side requests. The client-side relative URL is naturally resolved relative to the URL in the browser. When you change the path depth via URL-rewriting, you end up changing the base URL path from which these relative URLs are resolved.

The solution it is use root-relative (or even absolute) URLs throughout.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

This is typical of attempting to parse an HTML document as JSON. In other words, this "HTML document" is most probably the 404 response as a result of using the incorrect (relative) URL-path in your client-side script.